# UK Visa - 3 month in advance

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, applications

I want to apply for a UK visa, to visit a friend. I have to apply 3 months in advance but the visa could be granted sooner. Does this mean that the visa will be dated sooner than the 3-month application start date? Can I come to the UK sooner?

Answer (score 3):

The earliest you can apply is 3 months before you plan to travel https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor.

The UK doesn’t require applicants to provide travel bookings as part of the application paperwork (in fact, the official guidance says *not* to book in advance). You should assume that  if your visa is granted, it will start around the date of travel stated in your application.